# How do I mathematically create a set of vertexes in Blender, or import them?

Tags: import, mathematics, csv

Say I have external program-code, or spreadsheet,
that gives me the exact locations of vertexes for an aircraft's surfaces, e.g.,

and I need to create a mesh in Blender that has those vertexes,
not approximations of them.

My vertexes are roughly equi-angular to each other,
so at the leading-edge of the airfoils, the vertexes are dense,
but over the latter 1/3rd of the airfoils, the vertexes are less-dense.

I need to create meshes in Blender that have their vertexes exactly where my external program has placed them.

How do I get my thousands of vertexes, calculated externally, into Blender?

Do I create code in Blender Python that replicates my external code,
therefore creating the vertexes within Blender Python?

If so, how?  (showing me how to create an octagon of vertexes, in python, would give me enough, I think )

Do I use nodes to create the curves and then turn them into meshes?

Again, if so, how? (ditto with the octagon)

Or is there some way I can import a csv, or something, of my actual/calculated vertexes ( down to 0.1mm, say ), into Blender and have the vertexes appear, ready for connecting with edges, using a topology tool?

I've simply no idea where to begin, on this.

I *do not* want to by-hand model a sorta-looks-right representation:

I want the exact curves, the exact calculated geometry, gotten from my external program's results into Blender, even if that means replicating my code in Python.

I hope this makes more sense, & thank you for telling me my 1st version didn't, btw.

leaving 1st-version here, so people can understand other perspective on my problem:

Say I need to have an ellipse, or an egg,
and need to have all the angles between the vertexes be 4°, e.g.
or between 1.75-2°.

Obviously, the lengths of the edges between them are going to be all different.

How do I get from the math describing the curve,
to having a curve made of edges, *all equi-angular*?

Nodes or python?

Or is there some way to do the calculations outside Blender (preferred, in my case) and just import a csv, or something, identifying all the vertexes?

I want to code (outside of Blender) some mathematical forms,
(airfoils included) then get those into blender, as meshes, somehow,
and don't mind implementing both outside of Blender (where my real project is) & inside blender, but I simply don't even know where to begin.

I've seen no way of using math to create such curve-meshes in Blender.

Comment: This is probably a question better asked in a geometry / mathematics forum. As stated the problem is unclear and attempts to solve it, even in 2d are going to often fail because an equiangular approximation of a closed curve may not be possible for various ranges of angles.

Comment: You should provide more context and explain why you want to achieve this in order to avoid [xy problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) kind of situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [the Wavefront.obj](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) or [AC3D](https://wiki.flightgear.org/AC3D_file_format) file formats both are fairly simple text-based formats. Some time ago I wrote a parser for the USAF Digital Datcom that wrote out an AC3D model based on the FORTRAN input card decks. There is a copy of the [AC3D importer on my GitHub.](https://github.com/jentron/Blender-AC3D)

It would also be fairly trivial to write a basic importer for a CSV point list. Here is the Blender specific code with an example default cube hard coded in:

```
import bpy

collection=bpy.context.collection # the active collection

verts = [
( 1, 1, 1),
( 1, 1,-1),
( 1,-1, 1),
( 1,-1,-1),
(-1, 1, 1),
(-1, 1,-1),
(-1,-1, 1),
(-1,-1,-1),
]

faces = [
(0, 1, 3, 2),
(4, 5, 7, 6)
]

meshName = "Example Point Cloud"
mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new(meshName)
obj = bpy.data.objects.new(meshName, mesh)
collection.objects.link(obj)

mesh.from_pydata(verts, [], faces) # verts, edges, faces
```

Your task would be simply to populate the verts list by reading the tuples in from a CSV file and then skinning the object. If you don't have faces, just pass an empty list [] into from_pydata()

Answer (score 1):

You could make dense geometry with very small edge angles and use Limited dissolve to remove vertices based on angle. This way you can set maximum angle the edges of your mesh may have.